# Open Graph metatags in Dynamic Joomla articles

Tags: php, joomla, meta-tags

Goodmorning everybody

Using joomla extensions from market I can't customize the OG metatags about individual page

This is my php code in joomla article

```
<?php
$ide = $_GET['ide'];
require 'MY DIRECTORY'; $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass); mysql_select_db($db); $sql = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE id = ".$ide; 
//print $sql; 
$result = mysql_query($sql); while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{ 
$nome = $row['nome'];
$num_edi = $row['num_edi']; 
$data = $row['data']; 
$comune = $row['comune']; 
if ($row['tipologia'] == 1) $tipologia = "Competitiva";
if ($row['tipologia'] == 2) $tipologia = "Non Competitiva";
if ($row['tipologia'] == 3) $tipologia = "Ludico Motoria";
if ($row['tipo'] == 1) $tipo = "Rogaining";
if ($row['tipo'] == 2) $tipo = "Strada";
if ($row['tipo'] == 3) $tipo = "Skyrunning";
if ($row['tipo'] == 4) $tipo = "Trail Running";
if ($row['tipo'] == 5) $tipo = "Mud Race";
if ($row['tipo'] == 6) $tipo = "Corsa a tappe";
if ($row['tipo'] == 7) $tipo = "Marcia";
if ($row['tipo'] == 8) $tipo = "Corsa in salita";
if ($row['tipo'] == 9) $tipo = "Campestre";
if ($row['tipo'] == 10) $tipo = "Vertical Km";
if ($row['tipo'] == 11) $tipo = "Allenamento/TA";
if ($row['tipo'] == 12) $tipo = "Retrorunning";
if ($row['tipo'] == 13) $tipo = "su fondo misto";
if ($row['tipo'] == 14) $tipo = "Pista";
if ($row['tipo'] == 15) $tipo = "Staffetta";
$ora = $row['ora'];  
$indirizzo = $row['indirizzo']; 
$provincia = $row['provincia']; 
$regione = $row['regione'];
$volantino  = $row['volantino'];  
}
?>
<head>
<style>
#jm-footer{
  display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<div>
<h1><?php print $nome ?></h1>
<h4><span class="jm-text-color"><?php print $num_edi;?>&deg; edizione</span> - manifestazione <span class="jm-text-color"><?php print $tipologia ?></span> specialit&agrave; <span class="jm-text-color"><?php print $tipo ?></span></h4>
<h5><span class="jm-text-color"><?php print $comune ?></span> - <?php print $date ?> - <?php print $ora;?></h5>
<div>
```

so i can obtain a web page like this http://www.sportcalendar.it/scheda-gara.html?ide=793

If I use plugins that automatically generate metatags I get

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- load core head -->
  <base href="http://www.sportcalendar.it/scheda-gara.html">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="og:type" content="article">
  <meta name="og:title" content="SportCalendar - Prossimi Eventi">
  <meta name="og:url" content="http://www.sportcalendar.it/scheda-gara.html">
  <meta name="og:site_name" content="SportCalendar">
  <meta name="og:description" content=" torna alla ricerca">
  <meta name="og:image" content="http://www.sportcalendar.it/images/icon_sc.png">
  <title>SportCalendar - Prossimi Eventi</title>
```

I would like to replace the contents of OG metatags in this way

```
<meta name="og:type" content="article">
<meta name="og:title" content="<?php print $nome ?>">
<meta name="og:site_name" content="SportCalendar">
<meta name="og:description" content="<?php print $num_edi;?>&deg; edizione - manifestazione <?php print $tipologia ?> specialit&agrave; <?php print $tipo ?> presso <?php print $comune ?> - <?php print $date ?> - <?php print $ora;?>">
<meta name="og:image" content="http://www.sportcalendar.it/images/volantino/'.$volantino.'">
```

If I try directly enter this code in HEAD section of joomla article it is AUTOMATICALLY deleted

how do I get it?

Comment: Please make your question more precise, by explaining what OG means. Give a bit of context, and show what you want to get (and pehaps what for, perhaps there is another, better solution than what you propose).

Comment: Thank you. I changed Question description